# PDFBox: working with very large PDFs.

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working with some very large PDFs, some over 7GB in size. The PDFs have up to 20,000 pages and many full page color images. I'd like to use PDFBox to work with the PDFs, but due to the size I get OutOfMemoryError's when I attempt to open the PDFs.

I'm working with version pdfbox-app-1.6.0, on Windows 7 using Intellij, java 6.

First I tried writing a simple program that just opened the PDF in a PDDocument and coping each page over to another PDDocument: http://ideone.com/arKhB

Next I tried using the PDFBox [CopyDoc](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/persistence/CopyDoc.html) example.

Both example run out of memory.

I'm assuming this is because PDFBox is trying to read the whole document into memory. Is there a way to have it only open 1 page at a time? I know it would be slower processing, but at the moment I can't process anything.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586257/read-pdf-uploadstream-one-page-at-a-time-with-java

Comment: probably split the pdf file to a list and loop over the list and read certain amount of pages at a time.

Comment: @DNA - Thanks for the link. I'd checked every question tagged with PDFBox before posting, but had missed that one in my search.

Comment: @Pengo did you ever find any solution to this issue? In theory, you might just have increased memory usage with -Xmx20000M or more and made use of virtual memory or installed more. I have much smaller PDFs and they use 20 GB memory during the save operation. I was told no way to avoid this, just a library issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the 2.0.* versions, open the PDF like this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

This will setup buffering memory usage to only use temporary file(s) (no main-memory) with not restricted size.

Update 17.4.2018: More tricks to save memory are described in the [FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html). Not yet described but active since 2.0.9 is subsampling (skip pixel lines/rows) with `PDFRenderer.setSubsamplingAllowed(true)` when doing rendering. This saves space for PDF files with huge image files.

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue but insetad I am dealing with words (text) in pdf files. I tried to index like 10 million words in a single pdf file and it gives me out of memory error:java heap space. I tried your sugggestion above but it still doesn't fix it. Any other idea to try?

Comment: more memory with -Xmx . And always make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version.

Comment: I'm using PDFBox 2.0 . Also I tried altering -Xmx. It  stills throw out of memory

Comment: which 2.0 ? And what -Xmx value? I use -Xmx1g and sometimes -Xmx4g for my work. If it still doesn't do it, the best would be to share the PDF, the smallest possible code that reproduces the error and create a new question with this. But I wonder what kind of PDF would have more than a million words?

Comment: Well I'm just trying to stress test to see how much the PDFbox can deal with such issues.